# Initial Directory on filedialog in Delphi

Tags: delphi, filedialog

I need to know how to set the initial directory using the example from this link.

[TFileOpenDialog in FireMonkey Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998309/tfileopendialog-in-firemonkey-application)

Here is the code I am using, It works fine other than being able to set the initial folder.

```
function WinVistaSelectFolder: String; 
var
  FileDialog: IFileDialog;
  hr: HRESULT;
  IResult: IShellItem;
  initfldr:ishellitem;
  FileName: PWideChar;
  Settings: Cardinal;
  Title: String;
begin
  hr := CoCreateInstance (CLSID_FileOpenDialog,nil,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IFileDialog, FileDialog);
  if hr = S_OK then
  begin
    FileDialog.GetOptions(Settings);
    Settings := Settings or FOS_PICKFOLDERS or FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM;
    FileDialog.SetOptions(Settings);
    FileDialog.SetOkButtonLabel('Select');
     Title := 'Select a directory';
    FileDialog.SetTitle(PWideChar(Title));
    hr := FileDialog.Show(0);
    if hr = S_OK then
    begin
      hr := FileDialog.GetResult(IResult);
      if hr = S_OK then
      begin
        IResult.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, FileName);
        Result := FileName;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the `TFileOpenDialog` component, then you need to set the [`DefaultFolder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFileOpenDialog.DefaultFolder) property.

If in fact you are using `IFileDialog` rather than `TFileOpenDialog`. Then you should use the [`SetDefaultFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775972.aspx) method. Alternatively, depending on your precise needs, [`SetFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761828.aspx) may be appropriate.

Comment: in FM there is no TFileOpenDialog only TOpenDialog. and TOpenDialog does not have a default folder property.

Comment: The question you linked to asks about using TFileOpenDialog in FMX which is possible. Perhaps you should take some time to ask a clearer question. Is your question just how to use IFileDialog? I note that you've not included error checking in your code.

Answer (score -3):

Use [GetCurrentDir](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetCurrentDirectory) to find out what it is, or [SetCurrentDir](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.SetCurrentDir) to change it. Both are found in the System.IOUtils namespace on the TDirectory class.

Comment: No. That's the process working directory. The question relates to the initial directory for the dialog.

Comment: Also, System.IOUtils is a unit rather than a namespace.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Units are Namespaces. If you don't otherwise specify the dialog to go to a specific directory then it uses the process working directory.

Comment: Not so. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi), *In Delphi, a unit is the basic container for types. In Delphi, a namespace is a container of Delphi units.*

Comment: As for initial directory you are wrong there too. It's much more complex than that. There are many nuances. For instance, the system remembers which directory an application last opened a file from. Furthermore, even if what you were saying were true, changing the process working directory to specify the initial dir of a file dialog is a ludicrous idea. Imagine the consequences and side effects if that were the way to do it.

Comment: Drop a `TFileOpenDialog` onto a form and have its Execute method run. You claim that the dialog will open in the process working directory. It does not. Since your answer has a great many problems I think it would be best for you to delete it. Considering that you are an Embarcadero employee its not really very good marketing for an Employee to be so far wide of the mark.